# Try to do a simple where in with an Ecto query, but the where in part is translating to TRUE

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

```
def all_for_me(query, user_id) do
    friends = Repo.all(from f in Friendship, where: f.user_id == ^user_id and f.status == 2, select: f.friend_id)

    from p in query,
      where: p.privacy == "public" or (p.privacy == "friends" and p.user_id in ^friends),
    select: p,
    order_by: [desc: p.inserted_at]
  end
```

the OR or (p.privacy == "friends" and **p.user_id in ^friends**) part is comming out as ((p0."privacy" = 'friends') AND **false**))

What am I missing?  I know it's late and I have probably been at it for too long, but need to crack this before bed!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, `friends` is an empty list. From the REPL session below it occurs that `x in ^[]` is effectively translated to `false` in raw SQL.

```
iex(7)> TestProject.User |> where([x], x.id in ^[Ecto.UUID.generate])  |> Repo.all
[debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."email", u0."password_hash", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" IN ($1)) [<<98, 168, 63, 177, 44, 237, 76, 176, 148, 149, 173, 48, 68, 96, 235, 60>>] OK query=1.2ms
[]
iex(8)> TestProject.User |> where([x], x.id in ^[])  |> Repo.all                  
[debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."email", u0."password_hash", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (false) [] OK query=1.1ms
[]
```